# Getting Volume by Path using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, disk-partitioning

I know my volume has this path, and it's inside Disk number 3:

```
\\?\Volume{4c1b02c1-d990-11dc-99ae-806e6f6e6963}\
```

How do I get the actual Volume object using the Path to locate it?

I have tried with

```
Get-Volume -Path '\\?\Volume{4c1b02c1-d990-11dc-99ae-806e6f6e6963}\'
```

but it returns null. BTW, the partition related to the volume isn't formatted yet. I want to get access to the volume in order to use `Format-Volume` with it.

---

## EDIT

I've run these commands on the disk and I correctly get the partitions. However, I'm unable to get the volumes of some partitions as you can see below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take the `DeviceID` and work backwards, you need to look at [wmi](/questions/tagged/wmi):

```
$vol = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Volume -Filter 'DeviceID="\\\\?\\Volume{4c1b02c1-d990-11dc-99ae-806e6f6e6963}\\"'
```

Note: I don't have an unformatted volume on a Win10 device, so you'll need to figure out which parameter set corresponds to your use-case for `Get-Volume` based on the properties of `$vol`.

Comment: I'm getting "invalid query" :(

Comment: It's saying the same. I'm afraid it's unable to get volume

Comment: Same. I'm getting $null. Please, check my updated question. I've posted some interesting snapshots.

Comment: OK, I've used diskpart and discovered that there is no volume associated to the partition! how do I assign one?

Comment: @SuperJMN That's kind of outside the scope of your existing question.  You'd probably need to create one.  I'd start with looking up documentation for `New-Volume` and if you get stuck, ask a new question after trying some things.

Comment: You're right! I've created the right question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55222465/how-to-format-a-partion-not-a-volume-using-powershell