# How to format a partition (not a volume) using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, partitioning

I'm trying to format a partition programmatically. So far, I've tried PowerShell to do it, but it seems it requires a "volume" to do so.

To get the partition I want to format I use this:

```
$partition = get-disk -number 3 | get-partition | where Guid -eq "{0cdf62cf-64ac-468c-8d84-17292f3d63b7}"
```

What should I do next to format it?

## NOTE

I cannot format the partition using

```
Format-Volume -Partition $partition -FileSystem NTFS
```

This is what I get:

[image]

This might be of help. It's the contents of `$partition`. As you can see, it doesn't

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get-Partition` returns an object of type `CimInstance`. So you can use it with `Format-Volume`. Check documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/format-volume?view=win10-ps

```
PS X:\> $partition = get-disk -number 0 | get-partition | Where DriveLetter -eq "D"
PS X:\> $partition.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     CimInstance                              System.Object
PS X:\> Format-Volume -Partition $partition -FileSystem NTFS
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting this error message: Format-Volume : No matching MSFT_Volume objects found by CIM query for enumerating instances of the ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/Storage/MSFT_Volume class on the CIM server, that are associated with the following instance: MSFT_Partition (ObjectId = "{1}\\PEACH\root/Microsoft/Windows/Stora...). Verify query parameters and retry.

Comment: I think the problem is that the partition doesn't have an associated volume.

Comment: @SuperJMN, I'm not able to reproduce your error. Try my code on another partition to see if it works for you. Also can you print the content of `$partition`.

Comment: Please, take a look at the updated question with snapshots.

Comment: @SuperJMN is your disk (number 3) initialized ? Otherwise do `Initialize-Disk -Number 3` then create your partition `New-Partition -DiskNumber 3 -UseMaximumSize -AssignDriveLetter` and format it again.

Comment: It is initialized. The partition is already created. Why can't I just format it?

Comment: @SuperJMN, I don't know. I tried `$partition | Format-List` on my partiton and it has `IsOffline: False` but in your partition `IsOffline` is empty. Maybe that's why

Comment: from what i can tell ... you _cannot_ format a partition. you have to create a volume and then format _that_. [*frown*]

Comment: OK, @Fourat I had a problem with the GPT being corrupted. I fixed it and now it works!